# save cursor position of qtextedit

Tags: qt, qtextedit

[setCurrentCharFormat()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#setCurrentCharFormat) function does not take a current cursor position as a parameter. And so in order to set the char format for arbitrary text in the control I have to save the curent cursor position, set the char format and then restore it.

However, I don't see any thing like cursorPosition() in the docs.

Am I missing something?

Or maybe there is a better way of doing what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`QTextEdit::textCursor()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#textCursor) method which returns a *copy* of the editor's [`QTextCursor`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html). You can then manipulate the cursor as needed (including changing char. format and inserting text with [specific format](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#insertText-1)). If you need the cursor changes to persist (like the char. format), then make sure to `QTextEdit::setCursor()` afterwards.

A very basic example of inserting some text:

```cpp
  QTextCursor cursor(ui->textEdit->textCursor());
  cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::End, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor, 1);
  cursor.insertText(text);
```

---

ADDED:
Perhaps the Qt [Text Edit example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-richtext-textedit-example.html) will help. Specifically, in [textedit.cpp](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-richtext-textedit-textedit-cpp.html) where we see something like this:

```cpp
  void TextEdit::textBold()
  {
      QTextCharFormat fmt;
      fmt.setFontWeight(actionTextBold->isChecked() ? QFont::Bold : QFont::Normal);
      mergeFormatOnWordOrSelection(fmt);
  }

  void TextEdit::mergeFormatOnWordOrSelection(const QTextCharFormat &format)
  {
      QTextCursor cursor = textEdit->textCursor();
      if (!cursor.hasSelection())
          cursor.select(QTextCursor::WordUnderCursor);
      cursor.mergeCharFormat(format);
      textEdit->mergeCurrentCharFormat(format);
  }
```

---

2nd ADDITION (based on comment):

> So, if my cursor is at the line 3 col 10 and I call the function like this: SetCharFormat( 2, 5, attr ); it stores the current cursor position as (3, 10), then selects the text for text characters 2 and 5, set the text attribute for the selection, and then cursor will move back to the old position/selection.

Below is a specific example of what I think you're describing. One thing overall though, the text cursor position only has one dimension, which is, essentially, the number of visible characters from the start of the document. (The text cursor should not be confused with a `QCursor` which represents a mouse pointer with x,y coordinates.)

This simple test shows an editor with the text "I like this program." and a button. The button (or `Alt-D`) will toggle bold formatting on the word "like" while keeping the visible cursor position (and any selection) unchanged.

I've also included some sample code which moves the visible cursor initially, and in the formatting function there is a commented-out example of how to save and restore the cursor position programmatically.  It is not needed in this particular example because the visible cursor is never modified.

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets>

class Dialog : public QDialog 
{
  public:
    Dialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QDialog(parent) 
    {
      QTextEdit *textEdit = new QTextEdit("I like this program.", this);

      // Position cursor at end of sentence (just as an example)
      QTextCursor cursor(textEdit->textCursor());
      cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::End);
      textEdit->setTextCursor(cursor);  // required for the visible cursor to actually move

      QToolButton *btnTest = new QToolButton(this);
      btnTest->setText("&Do it");
      btnTest->setCheckable(true);

      connect(btnTest, &QToolButton::toggled, this, [textEdit, btnTest](bool checked)
      {
        // Function to toggle bold formatting on a section of text in the editor.
        const int start = 2;       // start of "like"
        const int end = start + 4; // length of "like"
        // the formatting to be applied
        QTextCharFormat format;
        format.setFontWeight(checked ? QFont::Bold : QFont::Normal);
        format.setForeground(checked ? QBrush(Qt::red) : QPalette().text());
        format.setBackground(checked ? QBrush(Qt::gray) : QPalette().base());

        QTextCursor cursor(textEdit->textCursor());          // get a copy of the editor's cursor
        // const int oldCursorPos = cursor.position();       // save cursor position (not needed for this example)

        cursor.setPosition(start, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);  // move w/out selection
        cursor.setPosition(end, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);    // move and select
        cursor.mergeCharFormat(format);                      // apply format to selection
        // cursor.setCharFormat(format);                     // alternative to mergeChatFormat()

        // cursor.setPosition(oldCursorPos);  // restore cursor position
        // cursor.setPosition(end);           // or move it to the end of the affected text
        // textEdit->setTextCursor(cursor);   // required for the visible cursor to move


        btnTest->setText(checked ? "Un&do it" : "Re&do it");
      });

      QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
      layout->addWidget(textEdit);
      layout->addWidget(btnTest);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  return Dialog().exec();
}
```

Comment: I think you misuderstood the secnario I am looking for. Lets say I have an empty QTextEdit. My user starts typing - "I like this program!" then while his cursor is sitting at the end (s)he wants to change the font representation for the word "like", and then go back to the end of the sentence.....

Comment: ... and so the scenario - 1. Grab cursor position as (x, y). 2 Change the styling of the arbitrary test in a range of (0, text.length() ) -i.e. Make the font bold. 3. Set the cursor position to be (x, y), so the user starts typing at the position (x+1, y).

Comment: @Igor So basically like a rich-text editor? The `QTextCursor` is still what you want to work on. But I would think in terms of selected text. So in your example you want to select the word "like" (see `QTextCursor::movePosition()` to select programmatically) and do some operation on it (see `QTextCursor::selection()`). You could then clear the selection and manually position the cursor with `QTextCursor::movePosition()` or `QTextCursor::setPosition()` afterwards.

Comment: @Igor I added an example from Qt docs to my answer, in case that helps.

Comment: I'm actually looking for something like `SetCharFormat(int start, int end, const TextAttr &attr);` function. which I can call with arbitrary start and end and after I return to caller restore the current position/current selection there was prior to call.

Comment: So, if my cursor is at the line 3 col 10 and I call the function like this: `SetCharFormat( 2, 5, attr );` it stores the current cursor position as (3, 10), then selects the text for text characters 2 and 5, set the text attribute for the selection, and then cursor will move back to the old position/selection.

Comment: @Igor See my latest addition. If I still don't understand you, perhaps use the code to provide a more specific standalone example of what you're looking for.

Comment: you latest addition is what I'm looking for. thank you. I will check if this works probably over the weekend and accept the answer if it will.

Comment: Now I tried to change to settings, and it didn'/t work. Should I apply them one by one?

Comment: @Igor Sorry, I don't understand "to settings."  Did you mean "two settings?" But I still don't know what that is asking. Like bold and italics as same time?

Comment: yes sorry. It should;ve been `two`. And its more like foreground and background color at the same time. Or foreground color with italic font.

Comment: Seems to work by just adding the attributes to the `QTextCharFormat format`. I added these two lines after `format.setFontWeight` and it worked: 
`format.setForeground(checked ? QBrush(Qt::red) : QPalette().text());` `format.setBackground(checked ? QBrush(Qt::gray) : QPalette().base());`

Comment: I guess in my case it is different because I'm trying to make it at the end of the text and apply it to the text that will be added.. Will the function changes?

Comment: @Igor I'm not sure... sounds like you're trying to do something different than in the example. Inserting/appending formatted text would be more like the first little snippet in my answer. Maybe post some code, and/or a new question.

Comment: the code you posted works perfectly if I want to change some existing char format. However if I want to change the char format for the text that will be added, it doesn't work. Going to your example - the text will be `I like this program.`, the cursor will stay at the end of this text and I will need to modify the char format for text that will be added there. So starting from position 20 (after the `.` symbol) I want the text to be with different char format. And I'm trying to make it in one function.

Comment: I mean modify the current function to handle both cases - changing the char format inside existing text and at end of the existing text.

Comment: @Igor Well, you could either append the text as plain and then use the formatting function on the newly inserted text. Or format the text first (perhaps using a shared formatting function) and then append it. Appending text is easy, shown in the fist code snippet of answer (visible cursor doesn't move). I personally probably would not overload one function to do both cases like you say, but this is a design decision.

Comment: does this mean I can;t set char format for the text that will be added

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195806/discussion-between-maxim-paperno-and-igor).