# Formating text in a Qtext edit

Tags: python, html, pyqt5, qtextedit

I am working on a Pyqt5 soft which can print a text in a qtext edit.

2 qcombobox allows the user to choose the text.

The text displayed in the qtext edit is loaded from json files.
This part of the soft is ok.

For now, i want the user to be able to edit the files ( i need to change style, especially put the text in bold).

I think that the best way to do it is with html, but i can’t manage the balise insertion.

I also face issues by selecting only part of the text.

i don't really understand the cursor/ anchor fonctions and don't have find explicit documentation.

Any one to give me an advice, or even part of the code that can help me ?

thank you in advance !

Comment: What you ask can't be easily answered, as accessing/editing a QTextDocument is not simple nor immediate, and requires a lot of studying and experimentation. I'd suggest you to start with understanding the [Rich Text Processing](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext.html), expecially the parts regarding the [document structure](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-structure.html), the [QTextCursor interface](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-cursor.html) and [editing tasks](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-common-tasks.html). Even though docs are C++ oriented, PyQt functions behave almost in the same way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56743582/save-cursor-position-of-qtextedit/56744212#56744212